# How to eliminate header and trailer in apache spark dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-databricks, pyspark

My dataframe looks like below in .dat format

```
_c0
This*is*header
siva*2121*123821*3123
sankar*2121*123821*3123
hraju*2121*123821*3123
santhi*2121*123821*3123
This*is*trailer
```

I want to remove first row This*is*header and last row This*is*trailer and '*' here is delimitter. I want to create dataframe as below with 4 columns. Please provide solution in python pyspark lbrary

Expected output in tabular format:

```
C1     C2     C3       C4
siva   2121   123821   3123
sankar 2121   123821   3123
hraju  2121   123821   3123
santhi 2121   123821   3123
```

Answer (score 0):

If the header and trailer have a different split count, then you can filter by count.

```
df.withColumn('array', split('_c0', '\*')) \
  .withColumn("count", size('array')) \
  .filter('count > 3') \
  .select(*[col('array')[i].alias('col' + str(i)) for i in range(0, 4)]) \
  .show()

+------+----+------+----+
|  col0|col1|  col2|col3|
+------+----+------+----+
|  siva|2121|123821|3123|
|sankar|2121|123821|3123|
| hraju|2121|123821|3123|
|santhi|2121|123821|3123|
+------+----+------+----+
```